# Update CGridView yii1 framework

Tags: yii, cgridview

Having tried all possible options, but the relation does not want to work. But I get this error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`user_id` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`store_id` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`status_id` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`bill_to_id` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`total` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`new` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`pay_method_id` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`created` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`updated` AS `t0_c9`, `t`.`billing_to_first` AS `t0_c10`, `t`.`billing_to_last` AS `t0_c11`, `t`.`billing_to_fax` AS `t0_c12`, `t`.`cc_last_four` AS `t0_c13`, `t`.`check_image_id` AS `t0_c14`, `t`.`comments` AS `t0_c15`, `t`.`warning_id` AS `t0_c16`, `t`.`artworkRec` AS `t0_c17`, `t`.`proofSent` AS `t0_c18`, `t`.`proofApprvd` AS `t0_c19`, `t`.`inHands` AS `t0_c20`, `orderItems`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `orderItems`.`order_id` AS `t1_c1`, `orderItems`.`product_id` AS `t1_c2`, `orderItems`.`factory_id` AS `t1_c3`, `orderItems`.`qty` AS `t1_c4`, `orderItems`.`price` AS `t1_c5`, `orderItems`.`logo_name` AS `t1_c6`, `orderItems`.`po_number` AS `t1_c7`, `orderItems`.`art_id` AS `t1_c8`, `orderItems`.`art_status_id` AS `t1_c9`, `orderItems`.`send_proof` AS `t1_c10`, `orderItems`.`art_comments` AS `t1_c11`, `orderItems`.`rush_option_id` AS `t1_c12`, `orderItems`.`special_instructions` AS `t1_c13`, `orderItems`.`misc_charge_name` AS `t1_c14`, `orderItems`.`misc_charge_amount` AS `t1_c15` FROM `tbl_order` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_order_item` `orderItems` ON (`orderItems`.`order_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (orderItems.po_number=213) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10

I have a table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Te9v.png)

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'invoices' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Invoice', 'order_id'),
        'billTo' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Address', 'bill_to_id'),
        'checkImage' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Files', 'check_image_id'),
        'payMethod' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PayMethod', 'pay_method_id'),
        'status' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Status', 'status_id'),
        'store' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Websites', 'store_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
        'warning' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'WarningsLog', 'warning_id'),
        'orderChangeLogs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'OrderChangeLog', 'order_id'),
        'orderItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'OrderItem', 'order_id'),
        'shipments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Shipment', 'order_id'),
        'warningsLogs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'WarningsLog', 'order_id'),
    );
}




public function search($array = null)
{


    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('t.id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
    $criteria->compare('store_id',$this->store_id);
    $criteria->compare('status_id',$this->status_id);
    $criteria->compare('bill_to_id',$this->bill_to_id);
    $criteria->compare('total',$this->total,true);
    $criteria->compare('new',$this->new);
    $criteria->compare('pay_method_id',$this->pay_method_id);
    $criteria->compare('created',$this->created,true);
    $criteria->compare('updated',$this->updated,true);
    $criteria->compare('billing_to_first',$this->billing_to_first,true);
    $criteria->compare('billing_to_last',$this->billing_to_last,true);
    $criteria->compare('billing_to_fax',$this->billing_to_fax,true);
    $criteria->compare('cc_last_four',$this->cc_last_four);
    $criteria->compare('check_image_id',$this->check_image_id);
    $criteria->compare('comments',$this->comments,true);
    $criteria->compare('warning_id',$this->warning_id);
    $criteria->compare('artworkRec',$this->artworkRec,true);
    $criteria->compare('proofSent',$this->proofSent,true);
    $criteria->compare('proofApprvd',$this->proofApprvd,true);
    $criteria->compare('inHands',$this->inHands,true);

    $criteria->with = array('orderItems');

  //        $criteria->compare('orderItems.order_id', $this->id, true);

   $criteria->addCondition('orderItems.po_number=213');

    $criteria->together = true;


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',
        ),
    ));
}
```

I would be glad of any help

Comment: `id` column is used twice in your query. put alias before id like `u.id` also commit out this line `$criteria->with = array('orderItems');`

Comment: I do not quite understand, you can lead a full example

Comment: If I added it 
$criteria->with = array('orderItems');
  $criteria->alias = 'u.id';
I have error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'t.id DESC',
        ),